# Why this kind of recursion wouldn't exceed recursion limit

Tags: python, multithreading, recursion

First I would like to use threading.Timer to do an endless loop,  After I do that, I was worried that the recursion function would exceed recursion limit in Python, however, after I test as follow, I find that the recursion function would execute forever. Why is that?

```
import threading
recursion_count=0
def recursion(count):
    count=count+1
    print("recursion_count:  %d\n"%count)
    t = threading.Timer(0.1, recursion, (count,))
    t.start()
if __name__=='__main__':
    recursion(recursion_count)
```

Comment: is there any condition to break the recursion in your code?

Comment: Simply said: new thread, new recursion limit. The limit is there to protect you from mistakes and edge case, it still allows you to shoot yourself in the leg intentionally.

Comment: I see no recursion there.

Answer (score 0):

The simple reason why this doesn't exceed any recursion limit is twofold:

1. As mentioned, the stack recursion limit is per thread. Since you're launching new threads, it doesn't apply to them.
2. Recursively spawing new threads won't exceed thread limits either, because you only have at most two of them running at the same time. One thread creates a new one (which initially doesn't do anything for 100ms) and then terminates.

If you want to exceed limits, wait for each started thread to finish from the thread that started it.